# What are the differences between Paranoia XP/25th Anniversary and Paranoia 2017?

Tags: edition-comparison, paranoia, paranoia-2017

The 2017 version of *Paranoia* (which unfortunately is just called *Paranoia* without any edition subtitle that I can find) appears to be pretty different from Paranoia XP/25th Anniversary ([which were pretty much the same version](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9565/7373)). What are all the notable differences between this version and the previous one? Is anything from that edition compatible or will it require some sort of conversion?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've changed it to refer to the pervious version, Paranoia XP/25th Anniversary. For what it's worth, editions in Paranoia are wonky. After the 2nd was published, the 5th was published (and later declared an "un-edition" due to poor reception). Then there was an unpublished 3rd edition, then XP, then 25th Anniversary (which was just XP with a few textual revisions). Calling this version 6th edition is kind of unintuitive.

Comment: I was vaguely aware that *Paranoia* has had a troubled history, but I was unaware that it was quite *that* troubled! Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: +1 because I too want to know, having only played 2nd.  I loved it soo much I even wrote a screensaver :P

Comment: Definitely get the new version :D  @okeefe has a great description of differences, plus the A4 size (travel journal) is easy to throw in a bag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Minor, on-the-fly conversions will smooth things over, but fundamentally [Paranoia missions don't depend on the version of the rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77175/307).

- Most of the Secret Societies still exist, but some were removed or replaced and a few new ones were added. The scope of Secret Societies were also changed—it's fine if they're freshly created and tiny. Also, Internal Security is now a Secret Society, which makes some sense.
- Likewise, some Mutant Powers were changed or replaced.
- Troubleshooters no longer belong to a Service Group (IntSec is special, see above). Service Firms basically don't exist as play concept but can certainly still exist in Alpha Complex. Slight tweaks to Mandatory Bonus Duties as well.
- Players make all the dice rolls, which are now d6 dice pools rather than a d20. Weapons and damage are simplified. Character generation is done as a group, whereas you might use pregenerated characters in earlier editions.
- It's probably more convenient to replace uncommon (but not experimental) equipment with the new equipment cards.
- Add terrorists to the list of things The Computer is concerned about for the safety of Alpha Complex.
- Cerebral Cortech is new and replaces some forms of surveillance The Computer might use, adds new ways to communicate and record suspicious activities, and provides new ways to screw the players.